# Overwrite foundation buttons

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

The documentation (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html) doesn't say anyting about changing the background of a button. How can I do this in sass (custom.scss)?

I can't create a new buttonclass because I need to change the styling of generated components in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not create a new class, can't you just extend the existing class?

You can just do this:

```
button,
.button,
a.button,
input.button
{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: this is not the foundation way

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot add comment so I will just write it as an answer. Do you want to change background color of all buttons? There is a file for you to customize these settings, by default these are commented. You will find some lines for background color settings like this: 
In Foundation 5, its in `_setting.scss`

```
// $primary-color: #008CBA;
// $secondary-color: #e7e7e7;
// $alert-color: #f04124;
// $success-color: #43AC6A;
// $warning-color: #f08a24;
// $info-color: #a0d3e8;
```

Uncomment the line you want to customize settings and change the value of color as you want. In the file that you define styles for buttons, `@import` the file that has customized settings (`_settings.scss` in this case). This will also change color of other elements importing the customized setting file.

Another way, go to definition for `@mixin button` and change value of `$bg`as you want.

```
&.secondary { @include button-style($bg:$secondary-color); }
  &.success   { @include button-style($bg:$success-color); }
  &.alert     { @include button-style($bg:$alert-color); }

&.disabled, &[disabled] { @include button-style($bg:$primary-color, $disabled:true);
    &.secondary { @include button-style($bg:$secondary-color, $disabled:true); }
    &.success { @include button-style($bg:$success-color, $disabled:true); }
    &.alert { @include button-style($bg:$alert-color, $disabled:true); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these properties in your SCSS file.

```
$button-background  - Background color of the button.

$button-background-hover - Background color of the button on hover. 

$button-color - Text color of the button.
```

Source: [Foundation CSS - Buttons](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/button.html)